# Append onload ajax response while DOM creation, as soon as the reference node is created in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I need to append ajax response(which is an html) to a reference node while DOM creation. The ajax is called while loading the page. So as soon as the reference node is created, I want to append the returned html from ajax to the reference node. I have used jquery .after(), but it doesn't work on first load of page. So, is it possible to achieve this functionality? If it is, how should I proceed? 
Here's, what I want to achieve:

```js
1) DOM creation started
2) var ajaxResponse = getAjaxResponse();
3) Reference-node creation started
4) As-soon-as-Reference-node-is-created-in-the-DOM -> 
5) $('#reference-node').append(ajaxResponse);
6) end of DOM creation
```

NOTE: "#reference-node" does not come from ajax response, it is part of main page.

Comment: store a promise of the data in a variable (hint: if you're using jquery.ajax, it returns a Promise) ... wait for the promise to resolve in document ready (since you're using jQuery), or in a script tag  just after the reference node, or in code that creates the reference node

Comment: First do the API request using `.ajax()` chained with `.done()` or `.complete()` (depending on the jQuery version) then proceed to `.append()` or `.appendTo()` the content you received

Comment: what if it finishes before he reference node exists @Ferie

Comment: The DOM is alway there before the API request respond. You just need to append the answer to an existing node in the DOM.

Comment: @JaromandaX, using promise, it is not appending the ajax response to the reference node as soon as reference node is created. It appends only after second load of page happens. Here's what I did:                                             $('#id-of-reference-node').promise().done(function() {                         ajaxResponse = getAjaxResponse;                                                                   $('#id-of-reference-node').append(ajaxResponse);}

Comment: `$('#id-of-reference-node').promise()` I don't know what this does, and it's not at all what I suggested

Comment: @JaromandaX, I am not able to comprehend as to how to implement your solution, can you please enlighten me on that?

Comment: I'd show some code ... but not sure if it could help since I have no idea what your code looks like

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have updated the description, kindly check if it helps?

Comment: here's a pseudo code answer to your pseudo code update `const dataPromise = getDataAsynchronouslyReturningAPromise();
whenReferenceNodeIsCreated(() => {
  dataPromise.then(result => doSomethingWithResult(result));
})`